What does שרית עם אלהים mean?
Last week's sedra. Yaakov was called Israel by the angel כי שרית עם אלהים ועם אנשים ותוכל.
There are some heretics who use this verse to mean that we are called the people of Israel cos we are able to wrestle with God and beat him ch"v. Afra lepumayhu.
(I could have thought that the word elohim refers to an angel, which is very apropos, considering he had just fought with the angel and with men (Lovon and Esov). Or it could be referring to God. The Targum clearly translates elohim as God.
The simple reading of the posuk would seem to refer to elohim as in "the angel who he just fought with", no? Perhaps these heretics don't believe in angels.
It would seem to me that the posuk in Hoshea that Rashi brings, is more indicative of an angel. It says וישר אל מלאך ויוכל, which is an exact parallel of our posuk but replacing the word שרית for וישר which would seem to be the same word, as well as replacing elohim with hamalach.)
Regardless, if the posuk truly does refer to God as the targum says, then I have two questions:

What is vatuchol (ותוכל)? Does that not denote victory? How could one be victorious against god?
What does שרית mean? Translating it as "wrestling" is totally incompatible with god. The targum translates איתרברבת from the loshon of sorus (שרות) meaning lordship, grandness.  In short, where do they get soriso (שרית) meaning "wrestling"? Is it just a play on words? Ris-res. Based off the vayeovek (ויאבק) which means wrestle.

Thanks

Re: There are some heretics who use this verse to mean that we are called the people of Israel cos we are able to wrestle with God and beat him ch"v. - On the other hand, "nitzchuni banai" (https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.59b.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi).

The Moreh Nevuchim was written to help with questions like this. If the Torah and the Targum say it's possible to wrestle with God, then you need to understand that this is true, but not literal. The first 50 or so chapters give dozens and dozens of examples of how to take a word like that as is applied to God and understand it properly.

Wrestle means like in a court against an accuser regarding the meaning of service to G-d and purity of one's actions.

"Wrestling with G-d" (שרית עם אלהים) and being victorious can also mean G-d as expressed within the natural world. That אלהים is הטבע. That the Jewish people, via their service through Torah and Mitzvot, reveal and connect with G-d who transcends the constraints of the natural world (יהוה). This is the concept of miracles (נסים) and wonders(נפלאות).

A number of meforshim (e.g, Rashbam, Radatz Hoffman) on that pasuk say that שרית derives from שרה, which means struggle, see https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dictionary/8280, which can lend itself to wrestle. Others (e.g., Ralbag, Seichel Tov) see it as deriving from שרר, which denotes supremacy, see https://mg.alhatorah.org/#!Dictionary/8323.

Thanks.  But how do these meforshim translate elohim and vatuchol.    If it really means a fight. Must they therefore say that the struggle is with an angel and it with God.  And if they say elohim is with God, must they therefore say that vatuchol does not denote a victory?  It's all one big question.  How do you translate soriso, who is elohim, and how do you translate vatuchol.

The commentators on Onkelos explain that he veered from rendering elohim as an angel (as do Targum Yerushalmi and Yonasan) to avoid the connotation that one can physically struggle with them. Once Onkelos renders it as such he is then foreclosed from explaining that Yaakov vanquished God and therefore bifurcates the pasuk as follows: He said, “No longer will your name be spoken of as Yaakov, but as Yisrael, for you are great before Hashem, and with men you have won.” See  https://onkelos.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/32.29#e0n6

I don't believe there's any disagreement regarding vatuchal in that it denotes victory.

In other words, if one renders 'elohim' as angel (as do the other targumim) then one can interpret 'sarisa' as איתרברבת. However, if, as Onkelos, one explains elohim as kodesh (ie God), then, owing to your question one must interpret 'sarisa' as רב/great (before God), but not that he vanquished God (or an angel, for that matter). The commentators say that the reliable manuscripts of Onkelos possess רב—not איתרברבת.
